# vulkan: pWaitDstStageMask member in VkSubmitInfo

Tags: vulkan

In `VkSubmitInfo`, when `pWaitDstStageMask[0]` is `VK_PIPLINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT`, **vulkan** implementation executes pipeline stages without waitng for `pWaitSemaphores[0]` until it reaches Color Attachment Stage.

However, if the command buffer has multiple subpasses and multiple draw commands, then does `WaitDstStageMask` mean the stages of all draw commands?

If I want `vulkan` implementation to wait the semaphore when it reaches color attachment output stage of the last subpass, what should I do?

Comment: Do you know the answer to this question now "However, if the command buffer has multiple subpasses and multiple draw commands, then does WaitDstStageMask mean the stages of all draw commands?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't actually want to do this. On hardware that benefits from multi-subpass renderpasses, the fragment work for the entire renderpass will be scheduled and execute as essentially a single monolithic chunk of work. E.g. all subpasses will execute for some pixel (x,y) regions before any subpasses are executed for some other pixel (x,y) regions. So it doesn't really make sense to say insert a synchronization barrier on an external event between two subpasses. So you need to think about what your renderpass is doing and whether it is really open to the kinds of optimizations they were designed for.

If not, then treating the subpasses (or at least the final one) as independent renderpasses isn't going to be a loss anyway, so you might as well just put it in a separate renderpass in a separate submit batch, and put the semaphore wait before it.

If so, then you just want to do the semaphore wait before the COLOR_ATTACHMENT stage for the whole renderpass anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In such situation You have (I think) two options:

- You can split render pass - exclude the last subpass and submit it's commands in a separate render pass recorded in a separate command buffer so You can specify semaphore for which it should wait on (but this doesn't sound too reasonably) or...
- You can use events - You should signal events after the commands which generate results later commands require, and then, in the last sub-pass You should wait on that event just before the commands that indeed need to wait.

The second approach is probably preferable (despite You are not using submission's `pWaitSemaphores` and `pWaitDstStageMask` fields), but it also has it's restrictions:

> `vkCmdWaitEvents` must not be used to wait on event signal operations occuring on other queues.

And I'm not sure, but maybe subpass dependencies may also help You here. Clever definitions of submission's `pWaitSemaphores` and render pass's subpass dependencies may be enough to do the job. But I'm not too confident in explaining subpass dependencies (I'm not sure I fully understand them) so don't rely on this. Maybe someone can confirm this. Bot the above two option definitely will do the trick.